# asp.net API visual studios. C #. A get or set accessor expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, var

I have the following code implemented. However, the compiler tells me:

```
A get or set accessor expected @ var

 public IEnumerable<Contacts> GetAllContacts
    {
        var Contacts = from c in dbc.Contact select c;
        return (IEnumerable<Contact>)Contacts;
    }
```

I am confused to why this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be a method, put parentheses after `GetAllContacts`.

```
public IEnumerable<Contacts> GetAllContacts()
```

If you want it to be a property, put in a `get` statement. (You should probably change the name to just `Contacts` if you want it to be a get statement, to be consistent with conventions.)

```
public IEnumerable<Contacts> GetAllContacts
{
    get 
    {
        var Contacts = from c in dbc.Contact select c;
        return (IEnumerable<Contact>)Contacts;
    }
}
```